# Restart IPython kernel

Tags: python, ipython

I am using Anaconda/Iphython 32bit on a Windows machine wit Python version 2.7. Every time I run a script (different Modules are called) and it fails, I need to close the program and open it again if I want to change the code. If I change the code without closing/opening IPython, my changes in the code are not “updated”.

I tired %reset, but it does not work. I tried ‘Ctrl’, ‘Ctrl+’. and ‘Crtl-‘ without success (nothing happen). 
It is really annoying because I have to change the Conda environment everytime and restart IPython :).
Any tips? Would be great

Comment: Even though it would be handy if %reset would clear the namespace and the cache for the imports (as in the notebook) one can explicitly reload a previously imported module using importlib.reload in python3.4 or imp.reload in python3.0-3.3 (and if needed reset the kernel in a second step).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I am using Python 2.7